# фрактал тип ошибки "fraktal() takes 2 positional arguments but 4 were given"

Tags: python

```
from turtle import*
def fraktal(x,y):
    for i in range(8):
        if Theorema[i]=='+':
            right(angle)
        elif Theorema[i]=='-':
            left(angle)
        elif Theorema[i]=='F':
            if level==0:
                forward(step)
            else:
                fraktal(Theorema,step/3,angle,level-1)

Theorema="F-F++F-F"
speed(0)
fraktal(Theorema,200,60,3)
```

Comment: Ну так вы передаете 4 аргумента.

Answer (score 2):

Вместо

```
def fraktal(x,y):
```

используйте

```
def fraktal(Theorema, step, angle, level):
```

---

Между прочим, согласно [PEP-8 - руководство по написанию кода на Python](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/pep-8-rukovodstvo-po-napisaniyu-koda-na-python.html#id26) старайтесь писать имя переменных строчными буквами — не `Theorema`, а `theorema`.